# Linux mkv packages for VLC

Tags: linux, mkv, vlc

The video converter incorporated in VLC warns me when I select the MKV format with the message: `This muxer is not provided by VLC. It could be missing.`

Is there an official list of these MKV-related packages?

[image: mp4 screenshot][image: mkv screenshot]

I'm using VLC 3.0.9.2 in an Ubuntu based distro.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an issue. VLC has many built-in codecs. MKV is not in them. So VLC rely on `libmatroska` to manipulate MKV. As VLC cannot know if you have it installed, it gives a warning. Check if libmatroska is installed or not, using dpkg or apt.

Comment: Using `apt`, it seems to be `libmatroska-dev` instead of `libmatroska`. I know it's not an issue, I just wanted to know the name of the packages. Does VLC need other packages for MKV appart from this one?

Comment: I found `libebml` is required by `libmatroska`. But there may be other packages requred to play MKV. MKV is basically a container, so obviously demuxer for audio and video codecs like mpeg, flac, ogg is required.  Again it need to Qt to draw the windows to display your MKV, so you may call it a dependency. Then comes PulseAudio/JACK to play sound. So your question is quite tricky.

Comment: You may ask VLC devs on this matter.